# Remove disabled member from distribution group for Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

Exemployee left the company quite a while back and was never removed from the list of allowed senders on this particular group.
How can I remove disabled member from distribution group for Exchange 2010? BTW I have got 242 Distribution groups objects.

So far I tried :

Firstly , I just want to fetch disabled users  list of **Acceptmessagesonlyfrom and AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers and AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers** within 242 distribution groups via for loop

then , I want to remove all of them

```
(get-mailbox "user logon").acceptmessagesonlyfrom |% { $_.name} | add-content  "c:/output/"
(get-mailbox "user logon").acceptmessagesonlyfromdlmembers |% { $_.name} | add-content  "c:/output/"
```

Comment: is there any comment about this ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not deleting their account from AD for some reason. This would disable their mailbox and remove any associations that mailbox has...

Comment: @JamesC. As I said above my messsage how can I remove all of them via powershell script ?Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

check the `RecipientType` of the obsolete users with `Get-DistributionGroupMember`.
For me it was `User` because the users are disabled.

```
Get-DistributionGroup | % {
  $dg = $_.Name ; Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ | % {
    if ($_.RecipientType -eq "User") {
      write-host ("Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity '" + $dg + "' -Member '" + $_.Name + "' -Confirm:`$False -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck")
    }
  }
}
```